# How to keep a hole saw together?

Tags: tools, drilling, hole-saw

A few times I have purchased hole saw kits, there is one center piece and bunch of [different sized saws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_saw#Adjustable) every time I have tried to use one them by the second or third hole they are coming apart... It gets very frustrating.  Now I just buy one that is together and the size I need.

It seems like having one center bit and several interchangeable hole sizes would be a great idea.  But I never get it to work in practice. Is there a secret to how to make them stay together, when you swap out pieces?

Comment: I haven't experienced this with my set.  Maybe has to do with the quality of the thread to tighten it?

Comment: Which variety of hole saw are you using? If it's the one with thin flexible blades that fit into slots in the arbor,  try switching to one with cup-style blades.

Comment: Judging by the photo, yes, that's your problem; "adjustable " hole saws are finicky beasts.

Comment: I have never had that problem, either. Do they come apart while drilling, when you take the saw out of the hole, or when exactly?

Comment: They come loose with usage, and each time come apart sooner, after a few holes they will not stay together for one hole.  [This is the type I used but it has been some years ago](http://www.harborfreight.com/34-in-2-12-in-bi-metal-hole-saw-assorted-set-14-pc-68990.html) Current design may have improved, the versions I have used did not have the drive pins as shown in Cathodes answer.

Comment: don't use pliers or any gripping tool to tighten screw on mandrel you will strip it i speak from experience

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not seen the type of adjustable hole saw you describe, perhaps it's a regional thing (I'm on the west coast USA), but the type I'm familiar with have a spring loaded collar with "drive pins" that mate with holes in the bottom of the saw bit itself.

I would buy **mandrel** like this:

[image: hole saw mandrel]

And a hole bit of the appropriate size which threads onto the *collar screw*:

[image: hole saw bit]

After the bit is threaded on, the collar is snapped forward and the drive pins engage two of the four holes in the bit's base and prevent it from moving.